# jq search for value and return scalar

Tags: json, jq

I'm a newbie with jq and struggling to bend it to my will.

I want to search a JSON object for any key with a given name and extract the value for the first occurrence in order to assign this to a bash variable for later use. e.g. with:

```
{ 
  "fruit":{
      "name":"apple","color":"green","sub":{
               "name":"crab-apple","color":"red","size":"small"
      }
   }
}
```

If I use:

```
jq -r 'map(.name)|.[0]?'
```

I get the output I am looking for, specifically "apple". OTOH

```
jq -r 'map(.size)|.[0]?'
```

results in

```
[
   null
]
```

Not a scalar value and not what I wanted to find.

Please don't tell me I should search based on other attributes or the structure of JSON object (unless you're going to explain how to do a depth-first vs breadth-first search).

Comment: `size` is inside `sub`, so your second example should be `map(.sub.size)|.[0]?`

Comment: Are you looking for a key at an arbitrary, unknown level of nesting?

Comment: "Please don't tell me I should search based on other attributes or the structure of JSON object"

Comment: Yes, at an aribtrary/unknown level of nesting.

Comment: `select()` is your friend. Don't assume `.[0]`, just filter out the things where the output is null.

Comment: Something like `.. | select(objects) | .size // empty` might work, but I'm fairly sure there's a more idiomatic way.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't return anything.

Comment: It does return *small* with your sample input.

Comment: Oh - I wasn't using a literal '..' thought this was just a styling thing. Didn't know it provided recursion! Nearly there now - this can return multiple rows (e.g. for 'name')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for something like this:

```
first(recurse | objects | select(has("name")) .name)
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/q0w-8PSQqkO)</sup>